# Syntax error trying to make a bash function that reduces angles

Tags: bash

I'm a bash noob writing my very first function. angle_reduce is in a file called bashcalc-functions.sh. I want angle_reduce to take in an angle (in radians) and output that angle reduced to [0, 2pi]. As I understand it, `%` in bash performs the remainder operation as opposed to the modulo operation, so I added in an if statement to account for that.

```
function angle_reduce {
        twopi=$(echo "8*a(1)" | bc -l)
        x=$(echo "$1%$twopi" | bc)
        if ["$x" -lt 0]
        then
                x=$(echo "$x+$twopi" | bc -l)
        fi
        echo "$x"
}
```

Then I run it like this:

```
~/bash_practice # . bashcalc-functions.sh
~/bash_practice # angle_reduce "-10"
-bash: [-3.71681469282041352312: command not found
-3.71681469282041352312
```

I don't know where this syntax error is coming from. Furthermore, it looks like the line inside the if statement isn't executing at all, since the output is still negative.

Comment: you should add space after `[` and before `]`

Comment: @ymonad 

I just did that - now the output is

-bash: [: -3.71681469282041352312: integer expression expected
-3.71681469282041352312

Comment: bash doesn't understand floating point arithmetic.  If the variable in question is a float, use `bc` for comparison.

Comment: I hope you are doing this as an exercise, and not actually writing this kind of code in `bash`: it's not a general purpose programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is less than 0, then it will start with `-`, so go with that

```
if [ ${x::1} = - ]
```

Answer (score 0):

bash's [ ] does not support floating point arithmetic. so you can use `bc` instead

Some `bc` implemetation can do the following (Maybe GNU bc ? ).

```
if [ $(bc <<< "$x < 0") = "1" ]; then
```

The following is only using bc standard so can be use in any `bc`

```
if [ "$(bc <<< "if($x < 0){1}")" = "1" ]; then
```

However Steven's answer seems simple an clean for this case.

Comment: Steven's solution works, but this one doesn't. output is

syntax error on line 1, teletype
-bash: [: =: unary operator expected
-3.71681469282041352312

Comment: can you check the output of `bc <<< "$x < 0"` ? it must be `1` or `0`

Comment: putting x=-3.14; bc <<< "$x < 0" into my prompt gives syntax error on line1, teletype

Comment: Some `bc` seems to give that `error:.. teletype` message. So maybe you are using different `bc` implementation with my machine. Comparison seems not in bc standard. So forget my answer. I will delete this answer later.

Comment: I just realized I'm not using GNU bc. Thanks.